# cannot see default civisualize displays in 4.6.10

Tags: 4.6, civisualize

don't know if i am doing something wrong but just installed civisualize into drupal 7 / civicrm 4.6.10 set up and if i try say
/civicrm/dataviz/contacts

i simply get text

Contacts Overview

contacts selected from a total of records
Type
Source of Contact
Gender
Day - Contact Created
Date - Contact Created

with no visuals

any thoughts would be welcome

---

thanks for the reply am attaching screen grab of the page view where i expected to see visualisation, have not seen any error reports and i did set path to extensions directory when i set previous extensions which appear to work fine

any further ideas more than welcome as this extensin would be really useful to us if we can get it working

[image: contacts page screengrab]

Answer (score 1):

check if you have any error message, eg about a missing d3 object

your error is most likely that the url for extensions isn't properly configured, so all the javascript needed to get civisualize working properly isn't there.

if you have firebug installed, or other developer extensions, you should see-in the net tab- that it's looking for the needed javascript at the wrong place